# Prove that the vector measure induced by a right-continuous function is $\sigma$-additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let

- $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$ and $$\mathcal H:=\left\{(s,t]:a\le s\le t\le b\right\}$$
- $\mathcal R$ denote the ring generated by $\mathcal H$
- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $g:[a,b]\to E$ and $$\mu((s,t]):=g(t)-g(s)\;\;\;\text{for }a\le s\le t\le b$$

Note that $\mu$ is an additive set function on $\mathcal H$, i.e. $$\mu\left(\biguplus_{i=1}^nA_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)\tag1$$ for all disjoint $A_1,\ldots,A_n\in\mathcal H$ with $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\biguplus_{i=1}^nA_i\in\mathcal H$.

> I want to show that if $g$ is right-continuous, then $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-additive set function on $\mathcal H$, i.e. $$\mu\left(\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_i)\tag2$$ for all disjoint $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal R$ with $\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\in\mathcal H$.

By definition of $\mathcal H$, it's clear that the condition on $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ implies $$A_n=(s_n,t_n]\tag 3$$ for some $a\le s_n\le t_n\le b$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $$(s_m,t_m]\cap(s_n,t_n]=\emptyset\;\;\;\text{for all }m\ne n\;.\tag4$$

---

If we were allowed to rearrange and assume that $$s_n\le t_n\le s_{n+1}\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\;,\tag5$$ then $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ would be nondecreasing with $$t_\infty:=\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}t_n\in[s_1,b]\tag6$$ and hence (since $g$ is right-continuous)

\begin{equation}\begin{split}\mu\left(\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\right)&=\mu((s_1,t_\infty])=g(t_\infty)-g(s_1)\\&=\lim_{N\to\infty}g(t_N)-g(s_1)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N(g(t_n)-g(s_1))\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)\end{split}\tag7\end{equation}

---

This rearrangement is allowed, for example, in the classical case where $E$ is replaced by $[0,\infty]$. However, in our situation we don't know whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)$ is absolutely convergent (or even summable).

> So, how can we proved the claim here?

Comment: In the classical case what matters is not so much that $E=[0,\infty]$, the point is that $g$ has bounded variation. Also that rearrangment is not possible in general, in the classical case. Consider writing $(0,2]$ as a union of a sequence of intervals covering $(1,2]$ (_decreasing_ to $1$), plus a sequence of intervals covering $(0,1]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What are you after with that consideration? Oh, and please feel free to assume that $g$ has bounded variation, if you're thinking that this helps to prove the claim.

Comment: Just pointing out that the situation is more complicated than you seemed to realize: The problem with rearranging things as you suggest is not just that it might affect convergence of the sum, in fact the family of intervals simply need not be an increasing sequence, (In fact it can't be an increasing sequence  - it can but need not be a decreasing sequence, the intervals could be ordered like any countable ordinal, reversed...)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm going to give a counterexample, but I seriously doubt that this is true without more hypotheses; I'm going to assume that $g$ has bounded variation.

And I'm going to switch left and right, letting $H$ be the collection of half-open intervals $[a,b)$ and assuming that $g$ is left-continuous; I'll explain why later.

If $I$ and $J$ are disjoint intervals we'll say $I<J$ if $x<y$ for $x\in I$ and $y\in J$.

Suppose that $C\subset H$ is a pairwise disjoint collection of intervals with union $[0,1)$.

First, about that rearrangement that supposedly works in the classical case: The problem with the rearrangement is not just that the rearrangement might change the sum; in fact the supposed rearrangement need not exist! Because $C$ simply need not be an increasing sequence of intervals. For example, $C$ could consist of an increasing sequence of intervals covering $[0,1/2)$ together with an increasing sequence of intervals covering $[1/2,1)$.

Once you see that example you realize that the intervals in $C$ can cover $[0,1)$ in more complicated ways. In fact Folland, in a note regarding the proof he gives for the classical case in *Real Analysis*, comments that $(C,<)$ can be order-isomorphic to any countable ordinal. His point is that this is why the proof of the lemma is a little intricate (I think he says "fussy"); in particular it can't be done just by taking that "rearrangement". But when I saw that comment I said to myself hmm, countable ordinal...

Here's a sketch of a proof - I believe all the omitted details are straightforward. First,

> > $(C,<)$ is well-ordered.

Suppose not. Then there exist $I_n\in C$, $n=1,2,\dots$, with $I_{n+1}<I_n$. Now the intervals $I_n$ decrease to a point $x\in[0,1)$. We have $x\in J=[a,b)\in C$. Hence $I_n\subset J$ for large $n$, contradicting disjointness of $C$.

So $(C,<)$ is isomorphic to a countable ordinal: We have a countable ordinal $\alpha$ and $C=\{I_\beta\,:\,\beta<\alpha\}$, with $I_\beta<I_\gamma$ if and only if $\beta<\gamma$. (This is why I swapped left and right: In the original formulation $(C,<)$ would be the order-reversal of a countable ordinal.)

Another definition: If $S$ is any set and $f:S\to E$ we say $\sum_{x\in S}f(x)=s$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite set $F\subset S$ such that $$||s-\sum_{x\in F'}f(x)||<\epsilon$$for every finite set $F'$ with $F\subset F'\subset S$. (Note it's easy to see that if $S$ is countable and the sum converges in this sense then it also converges in thhe more usual sense, using an ordering of $S$ as a sequence.)

We need to show that $$\mu([0,1))=\sum_{\beta<\alpha}\mu(I_\beta).$$In fact it's straightforward to show that$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{\beta<\gamma}I_\beta\right)=\sum_{\beta<\gamma}\mu(I_\beta)\quad(\gamma\le\alpha)$$by transfinite induction on $\gamma$.

(The fact that $g$ is left-continuous is used for limit ordinals $\gamma$. It may well be that we don't need to assume $g$ has bounded variation to show $\mu([0,1))=\sum_{\beta<\alpha}\mu(I_\beta)$, at least if we defined that sum in the obvious way by transfinite recursion. But this is not what we actually want to prove. We also have $C=\{J_n\,:\,n\in\mathbb N\}$, and what we actually want is $\mu([0,1))=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(J_n).$ That's clear if we define $\sum_{\beta<\alpha}$ as above instead of by recursion, but then bounded variation comes in.)

Comment: I think my claim is correct, if we're assuming that $g$ has bounded variation. The crucial observation is that, if $|μ_g|$ denotes the variation of $\mu_g:=μ$ (I guess that you can imagine the details behind this notation) and $|g|$ denotes the variation of $g$, then $|μ_g|=μ_{|g|}$. Since $g$ is right-continuous, $μ_{|g|}$ is $\sigma$-additive and hence has an extension to a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal R)$. This is not a complete argument for the claim, but I think that we can extend $\mu_g$ to a measure $\nu_g$ on $\sigma(\mathcal R)$ such that $|\nu_g|$ is the unique extension of $μ_{|g|}$.

Comment: (BTW, I don't understand why you care about nondecreaseness of $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ at all. In order to prove the $\sigma$-additiveness of $\mu$, we only need to consider (pairwise) disjoint $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. So, it's impossible that such an $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is nondecreasing.)

Comment: When I talked about increasing sequences of intervals I was referring to the ordering I"d defined on $H$, not to increasing with respect to inclusion. Your question seemed to suggest that if we cover $[0,1)$ by countably many disjoint elements of $H$ then they form an increasing sequence. The reason I care about that is it's not so, and the whole thing would be much simpler if it were so.